# Substitutes for unix shell commands for windows?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am developing a source code judging software.I have developed it on Linux platfrom UBuntu 12.04 LTS.

Now i want to deploy it on Windows.
I my software i am creating the commands as per the unix shell,saving them in a file and then executing the commands through file.
Here is a part of the code:

```
package codejudge.compiler.languages;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import codejudge.compiler.TimedShell;

public class C extends Language {

    String file, contents, dir;
    int timeout;

    public C(String file, int timeout, String contents, String dir) {
        this.file = file;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.contents = contents;
        this.dir = dir;
    }
    public void compile() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir + "/" + file)));
            out.write(contents);
            out.close();
            // create the compiler script
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir + "/compile.sh")));
            out.write("cd \"" + dir +"\"\n");
            out.write("gcc -lm " + file + " 2> err.txt");
            out.close();
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec( dir + "/compile.sh");
            p.waitFor();
            p = r.exec(dir + "/compile.sh"); // execute the compiler script
            TimedShell shell = new TimedShell(this, p, timeout);
            shell.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void execute() {
        try {
            // create the execution script
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir + "/run.sh")));
            out.write("cd \"" + dir +"\"\n");

            out.write("./a.out < in.txt > out.txt");
            out.close();
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(dir + "/run.sh");
            p.waitFor();
            p = r.exec(dir + "/run.sh"); // execute the script
            TimedShell shell = new TimedShell(this, p, 3000);
            shell.start();
            p.waitFor();            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i am running the same code on windows i am getting the following erros( ihave minGW installed on windows):

```
Codejudge compilation server running ...
Compiling garima.c...
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\codejudge-compiler\stage\1/compile.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at codejudge.compiler.languages.C.compile(C.java:41)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.run(RequestThread.java:65)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\codejudge-compiler\stage\1\err.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.compileErrors(RequestThread.java:90)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.run(RequestThread.java:66)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\codejudge-compiler\stage\1/run.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at codejudge.compiler.languages.C.execute(C.java:65)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.run(RequestThread.java:72)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\codejudge-compiler\stage\1\out.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.execMsg(RequestThread.java:106)
    at codejudge.compiler.RequestThread.run(RequestThread.java:77)
```

I have very little knowledge of win32 shell commands..what changes are required to be made to the code ie. which commands should be changed which do not run on windows? And what are their substittes for windows?

Comment: Is using cygwin an option for you?

Comment: never used it really? Even if i use it how would i redirect the requests to cygwin?

Comment: You would need to run the whole thing in cygwin shell

Comment: never done that how do i do that?

Comment: http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gnuwin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) for most tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Install Cygwin, while installing make sure to include all the Java compiler related stuffs. After installing Cygwin terminal will appear on desktop, open that terminal. On this terminal you can run almost every Linux commands with a fully virtualized Linux environment with bin,sbin,usr etc. directories. And, under cygdrive you'll get the windows drives. So, try it!